# Can you claim being a care giver against income tax in Canada?

Tags: canada, income-tax

My brother is on ODSP in a wheel chair. He lives with mom, she is care giver. Last year I ran across something where she can claim that on income tax. I gave it to her, she lost it, and I don't remember where I found it. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You should [call the Canada Revenue Agency](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/cntct/phn-eng.html), they have people to help you there, especially during the tax season.  I always find them very helpful, they are there to help.

Here is what I found by doing some web searching: [Line 318 - Disability amount transferred from a dependant](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns300-350/318/menu-eng.html).

But I would definitely call and ask directly, they will tell what you can claim and how.

Comment: @Bruce If you do call, it would be great if you update with an answer detailing what you find out.